# How can i get just the latest 2 records on each group when using GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, group-concat

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(type SEPARATOR '/') as types FROM `sems` GROUP by year
```

I just want to get the 2 latest record on each group

Comment: Which column(s) determine what is the "latest" record in each group?  Can you include sample data in your question?

Comment: Why must GROUP_CONCAT be a part of the solution?

Comment: I have 3 columns id(auto increment), type, and year. Im combining type that were group by their year. The problem is i just only need  to get the last 2 records based on id on each group

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` for this. You need an ordering column to define the *latest* record, I assumed `ordering_id`:

```
select id, group_concat(type order by rn separator '/') types
from (
    select id, type, row_number() over(partition by id order by ordering_id desc) rn
    from sems
) t
where rn <= 2
group by id
```

In earlier versions, one option is to filter with a subquery:

```
select id, group_concat(type order by rn separator '/') types
from sems s
where s.ordering_id >= (
    select s1.ordering_id
    from sems s1
    where s1.id = s.id
    order by s1.ordering_id desc
    limit 2
)
group by id
```

This assumes that `(id, ordering_id)` tuples are unique. If not, and there are ties in the top 2, all related records will be taken into account.

Comment: Unfortunately im not using 8.0 version

Comment: @AdorDomingo: I updated my answer with a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: I have 3 columns id(auto increment), type, and year. Im combining type that were group by their year. The problem is i just only need to get the last 2 records based on id on each group. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not too numerous, you can use:

```
SELECT id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(type ORDER BY ? DESC SEPARATOR '/'), '/', -2) as types
FROM `sems`
GROUP by year;.
```

The `?` is for the column used to define "latest"